# Merging two pandas data frame with common columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a lower triangular matrix and then I transpose it and I have the transpose of it.
I am trying to merge them together

lower triangular:

```
 Data : 
     0         1         2      3        
0  1         0         0        0
1  0.21      0         0        0   
2  0.31      0.32      0        0
3  0.41      0.42      0.43     0
4  0.51      0.52      0.53     0.54
```

transpose triangular:

```
 Data : 
     0         1         2      3      
0  1         0.21      0.31     0.41   
1  0         0         0.32     0.52 
2  0         0         0        0.53
3  0         0         0        0.54
4  0         0         0        0
```

Merged matrix:

```
 Data : 
     0         1         2      3      4      
0  1         0.21      0.31     0.41   0.51
1  0.21         0      0.32     0.42   0.52
2  0.31      0.32      0        0.43   0.53
3  0.41      0.42      0.43     0      0.54
4  0.51      0.52     0.53      0.54   0
```

I tried using [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) but I couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us using `combine_first` after `mask`

```
df.mask(df==0).T.combine_first(df).fillna(0)
Out[1202]: 
      0     1     2     3     4
0  1.00  0.21  0.31  0.41  0.51
1  0.21  0.00  0.32  0.42  0.52
2  0.31  0.32  0.00  0.43  0.53
3  0.41  0.42  0.43  0.00  0.54
4  0.51  0.52  0.53  0.54  0.00
```

Comment: Works fine  but it adds the two one's at index (0,0) and becomes 2, I guess I just have to subtract it, Is there a way other than subtracting ?

Comment: @Rookie check my output I do not see 2 at (0.0)

Answer (score 1):

How about just adding the two dataframes?

```
df3 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

BR

Comment: yours adds the index at (0,0) together